# Use Vue.js Prop to populate vForm data?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, laravel-5.8

I am still fairly new to using Laravel and Vue.js and have been having some problems when trying to submit data to be used in a modal form.

**overview.vue** is displaying some information and triggering the modal component

My modal element:

```
<EditTeamModal :existing="existing_team"/>
```

In my template I am triggering the following function

```
@click="getExistingTeam(membership.team)"
```

Which triggers the following method:

```
getExistingTeam: function (team) {
    this.existing_team = team;
    this.$bvModal.show('edit_team');
},
```

**EditTeamModal.vue**
In my modal component I have several inputs like the one following:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ $t('team.name') }} <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="text" v-model="form.name" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('name') }" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required/>
        <has-error :form="form" field="name" />
        <small id="nameHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Unique name of your team (155 character limit).</small>
    </div>
</div>
```

and am setting my props and vForm data as follows:

```
props: {
    existing: {
        type: Object,
        required: true, 
        default: {}
    }
},
//   middleware: 'auth',
data () {
    return {
        form: new Form({
            id: this.existing.id,
            name: this.existing.name,
            region: this.existing.region,
            website: this.existing.website,
            about: this.existing.about,
            membership_password: "",
            membership_password_confirmation: "",
            avatar: null,
        }),
    }
},
```

However, my form inputs are always blank...

I can access this.exists.name directly and get the proper expected data output, however it will not seem to populate into my form fields?!

Is there a proper way to pull data from a vue property into vForm form data?

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get the modal form data to update by adding the following to my **EditTeamModal.vue**

```
watch: {
    existing: function(val) {
        this.form.fill(this.existing);
    }
},
```